# Deploying MVC Spring application in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am deploying web-app on Tomcat. While deploying on IntelliJ's Tomcat7.0.65, everything works fine, and when I deploy it on standalone Tomcat server 7.0.56(XAMPP) and when I want to click to send form it it gives Status 404 Response. In addition, I am using apache tiles. Everything that is in my config.xml mapped works fine, only requestmappings that are not mapped in config.xml arent work.

Have you got any idea how to fix it? 
I put my code underneath.

RequestMapping that doesnt work:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNewWorkerButtonClicked(@ModelAttribute("order") OrderEntity newOrder, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {

    orderService.add(newOrder);
    return "redirect:/orders/all";
}
```

WEB.XML

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
```

@edit

my project files location:
[image]

Comment: It could be that the app failed to launch on Tomcat.  Are there log messages that tell you so?  Maybe your WAR file isn't correct.  Or the URL that IntelliJ is using to launch the app is correct; the one you give to the browser when you deploy it on Tomcat is not.  Correct the URL if the app launches successfully.

Comment: Thank you, It was hardcoded url problem. I got another problem connected with resources. It doesnt load images, css

Comment: Your CSS and images are not in the right place.  Sounds like you've got a WAR problem.

Comment: i edited main thread adding img with files location

Comment: Look at the /target where Maven created your WAR file.  Does that look correct?  If not, figure out what adjustments are needed to make it so.

Comment: In target there are these images. What should I put into tomcat? Just war file?
Other thing is when I check the artifact settings it tells that META-INF/MANIFEST.MF is missing.

Comment: The problem was that I hardcoded the path which was different on Intellij's Tomcat and standalone Tomcat. 
In addition:
path - "/sth" clear the actual path and go to ip:port:/sth
path -"sth" doesnt clear the actual path and go to ip:port/actual_path/sth